# How to export an environment variable from a Python script?

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

```bash
export FOO1=bar1
python -c "import os; os.environ['FOO2'] = 'bar2'" 
echo $FOO1 $FOO2 # prints "bar1"
```

How do I make the environment variable `FOO2='bar2'` accessible to the calling bash script?

Comment: You can't. A child process can not alter the environment of it's parent process. This is not language dependant.

Comment: You can't. This is the best you can do: `export FOO2=$(python -c "print('bar2')" )`.

Comment: @jordanm, at least, not without some ptrace black magic =)

Comment: This may work: `source <(python -c "print ('FOO2=\"inside python\"')")`

Comment: Create from your child process (i.e. Python program) a text containing the environment setting, and in the calling process source this file.